# Разбор текстовых файлов

Tags: bat, notepad++

Есть два текстовых файла. В одном из них есть данные с номерами договоров. В другом тоже самое + новые договора. Строк много. Как создать батник чтоб с первого файла брал номер договора, и искал в другом файле. Если есть, то оставить, если нет, то удаляет. В результате должен получиться новый текстовый файл с номерами договоров с первого файла, т.е. без новых договоров?

Comment: Вот не для батника задачка. Сделай на более вменяемом языке, хотя бы VBS. Или просто в Excel...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Верно подсказывают, в чистом bat такое реализовать сложно будет, получится труднопонимаемая каша, скрипт write-only. Уж лучше perl взять. Ну или powershell, раз уж винда. Навскидку посоветую посмотреть [это](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19012457/compare-two-list-and-find-names-that-are-in-list-one-and-not-list-two-using-powe) или сразу [тут](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/df6deca7-6210-415c-890c-8af88ac5e6a2/compare-two-text-files-in-powershell-and-if-a-name-is-found-in-both-files-output-content-from-file?forum=winserverpowershell)

```
$names1 = "C:\names1.txt"
$names2 = "C:\names2.txt"
$names3 = "C:\names3.txt"

Get-Content $names1 | ForEach-Object {
    $names1_Line = $_
    Get-Content $names2 | Where-Object {$_.Contains($names1_Line)} | Out-File -FilePath $names3 -Append
}
```

[Сюда](https://dotnet-helpers.com/powershell/compare-two-files-list-differences/) еще загляните:

```
Clear-Host
$strReference = Get-Content "D:\BLOG\Power Shell\Examples\Masterlist.txt"
$strDifference = Get-Content "D:\BLOG\Power Shell\Examples\ChildList.txt"
Compare-Object $strReference $strDifference
```